# How do I restrict a set of draggables to one droppable, and another set of draggables to a second droppables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a website where I have a set of draggables I want to restrict to only show it's information when droped into a specific droppable.

Here is my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 

$(function() {

    $(".draggablem").draggable({
        revert: true,
        opacity: .75,
        containment: '.container',

        cursor: 'move',
        cursorAt: {
            top: 25,
            left: 75
        }

    });

    $(".draggableo").draggable({
        revert: true,
        opacity: .75,
        containment: '.container',
        cursor: 'move',
        cursorAt: {
            top: 25,
            left: 75
        }

    });

    $(".dropable").droppable({
        activeClass: 'dragactive',
        hoverClass: 'drophover',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('drophighlight').find('p').html('<br />' + ui.draggable.children("span").text());
        }
    });

    $(".dropable2").droppable({
        activeClass: 'dragactive',
        hoverClass: 'drophover',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('drophighlight').find('p').html('<br />' + ui.draggable.children("span").text());
        }
    });

}); 
</script>
```

I want to restrict `.draggablem` to `.dropable` and `.draggableo` to `.dropable2`.

Thank so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A droppable has an option `accept` that you should set to the selector which matches your draggables.

```
$('.dropable2').droppable({
    ...,
    accept: '.draggableo'
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not extremely clear.

You can use the `accept` option to define what is allowed to be dropped but that isn't how you have phrased the question.

If any element is allowed to be dropped , but as question states only show when  a specific class is dropped:

```
$(".dropable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.is('.myAllowedClass')) {
            /* do highlight*/      

        }
    }
});
```